# Using linkify when not using any DB models to navigate to a detail view

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Disclaimer: I've only just started using Django, so am not sure on some of my approaches I've used so far, so feel free to point out anything im doing blatantly wrong!

I am putting together a simple display/insert/update django web app that interacts with a legacy database we have that runs on Teradata. With no support for teradata in django for models, I am simply using pyodbc to connect and query it directly and work with the data that way.

I now have the data being displayed in a table using the django_tables2 framework and would not like to link the primary column to a detail view.

The documentation says that the LinkColumn function is now deprecated and we should then use Linkify instead. I've tried playing around with it but cannot get it to work.

Here is my code I have so far:

tables.py

```py
class ResultsTable(tables.Table):
    DataBaseName = tables.Column()
    TableName = tables.Column(linkify={"business_data_display", (tables.A("TableName.pk"))})
    Version = tables.Column()
    TableKind = tables.Column()
    CreatorName = tables.Column()

    # Styling the table with some CSS
    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover table-striped'}
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('db_display/', views.db_display, name='db_display'),
    path('db_display/<str:table_name>/business_data_form', views.business_data_display, name='business_data_display'),
]
```

views.py

```py
def db_display(request):
    dbo = dbc.dbConnectionManager()
    query_result_as_dict = dbo.run_query('SELECT TOP 10 DataBaseName, TableName, Version, TableKind, CreatorName FROM DBC.TABLESV;')
    dbo.disconnect()

    table = rt(query_result_as_dict)

    #tables.RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, "db_display.html", {"table" : table})

def business_data_display(request, table_name):
    dbo = dbc.dbConnectionManager()
    query_result_as_dict = dbo.run_query('''SELECT DataBaseName, 
                                            TableName,
                                            Version,
                                            TableKind,
                                            CreatorName 
                                            FROM DBC.TABLESV 
                                            where TableName = '{table_name}' '''.format(table_name=table_name))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    else:
        form = BusinessDataForm(initial={'tableName' : query_result_as_dict[1]['TableName']})

    return render(request, 'business_data_form.html', {'form' : form})
```

When I navigate to localhost:8000/db_display then TableName column has no hyperlink on it so am not sure what has gone wrong with linkify

I have a feeling its to do with the accessor part, I am not sure what to put in there in my situation? All the examples I am able to find deal with applications that use db models.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by doing the following:

```py
import django_tables2 as tables

class ResultsTable(tables.Table):
    DataBaseName = tables.Column()
    TableName = tables.Column(linkify=("business_data_display", (tables.A("TableName"), )))
    Version = tables.Column()
    TableKind = tables.Column()
    CreatorName = tables.Column()

    # Styling the table with some CSS
    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover table-striped'}
```

It now builds the correct link to the detail view.